# gallery not opening pop up view effectless

Tags: html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$Templates_CSS}backbox.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$Templates_JS}prototype.compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$Templates_JS}scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$Templates_JS}lightbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$Templates_JS}dhtmlHistory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$Templates_JS}customsignsheader.js"></script>
</head>
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="heading">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FF9900">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" background="{$Templates_Image}header_bg.jpg">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="heading"><span>{$gallery_title}</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" bordercolor="#666666" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="4">
                                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%">{section name=menuimg loop=$Loop} {if $smarty.section.menuimg.index > 0 && $smarty.section.menuimg.index%4 == 0 }</table>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" width="947">
                                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%">{/if} {if $smarty.section.menuimg.index == 0}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    <table class="stdTableBorder" width="3%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><a href="{$img_path_pro}big_thumb_{$gallery_images}" rel="lightbox[slide]">
        <img src="{$img_path_pro}medium_thumb_{$image_name[menuimg]}" width="198" height="135" border="0" class="imgAction"/></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>{else}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    <table class="stdTableBorder" width="3%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><a href="{$img_path1}big_thumb_{$image_name[menuimg]}" rel="lightbox[slide]">
            <img src="{$img_path1}thumb_{$image_name[menuimg]}" width="198" height="135" class="imgAction"  /></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>{/if} {/section}</table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="bodytextblack">&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$Templates_JS}customsignsfooter.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show us some javascript code of what should handle the popup? 
And what have you tried already? / Can you make an working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: There Is 5 javascript what u want..I have create dynamic gallery..gallery photo upload in admin panel..i photo add nd show in front side ..i have set javascript nd css nd in href i have set all values                                            "<a href="{$img_path1}big_thumb_{$image_name[menuimg]}" rel="lightbox[slide]"><img src="{$img_path1}thumb_{$image_name[menuimg]}" width="198" height="135" class="imgAction"  /></a>'                                                   when i click image only big thumb of image open..without zooming effect or button